# JavaFX - MVPC Pattern - separate FXML objects and event handler methods

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

I would like to create an application in JavaFX which imlements an MVPC pattern.
My idea is the following:
[image: MVPC model]

- VIEW: simple FXML file
- CONTROLLER: contains the event handler functions defined in VIEW, updates the PRESENTATION MODEL
- PRESENTATION MODEL:simple data, contains observable objects (ObjectProperty, ObservableList etc.)
- PRESENTER: contains the JavaFX nodes defined by fx:id in the FXML file, binds these nodes to the observable objects in the PRESENTATION MODEL and handles other presentation functions like popup windows. This would be the JavaFX Application.

As you could notice my aim is to separate FXML object (like @FXML Label label) to PRESENTER and FXML event handler methods (like @FXML submit(Action event e){}) TO CONTROLLER.

In short: I have ONE FXML file with elements like fx:id="passwordField" and event handlers like onAction="#browseSbx". I would like to have TWO separate .java controllers, one to contain objects for fx:ids and one to handle event methods.

My question: is there any "clean" way to do this? Or is there any conceptual error in my plan?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I understand very well your question... You want to create separate .fxml files for views, controllers, presentation-models and presenters? Or you want to separate the Java code in separate Java files?

Comment: Sorry. I have only one FXML file with elements like fx:id="passwordField" and event handlers like onAction="#browseSbx". I would like to have two separate .java controllers, one to contain objects for fx:ids and one to handle event methods.

Comment: Then you must import all the .fxml files that you need in you java class. You can specify in the .fxml class what controller you use in association with that  .fxml file.

Comment: As I said, I have ony ONE .fxml file. I need to connect two separate controllers to one .fxml file.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if you can associate more controllers to your single file, but I suggest you to use a GenericController and extend your GenericController in your CustomControllers classes :)

Comment: It is an interesting idea, but I don't understand completely how do you suggest to implement it

Comment: @DinaBogdan Not sure how that would help at all. You would still have just one controller instance.

Comment: Let's suppose you create a GenericController class file that you will asign to the unique .fxml file, where all the FXML objects are bindit with @FXML annotations. After that you can create custom-controllers classes that extends the GenericController class and with get and set methods from the super object, you can return the instances of the FXML objects from the .fxml file.

Comment: @DinaBogdan But you still have one controller instance. The OP wants two different *objects* (not merely two classes), one to bind the controls and one to handle user input.

Comment: @James_D You can make that generic class an abstract class that can not be instantiated and after that, creating two different class, can create two different intances of two different object type. One for controls and another one for handle user input

Comment: @DinaBogdan Please post an answer if you think you have one. It's really not clear how you intend to do the difficult part: associating the handlers defined in FXML with one object and the elements in the same FXML with `fx:id` attributes with the other object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note on usability: if you completely separate out the "actions" from the "view" (i.e. if your controller truly knows nothing about the UI components) things may get a little convoluted. For example, much of the time button actions will want to look at the state of text fields, etc. You certainly *can* do this by using your presenter to bind, say, the text in the text fields to data in the presentation model, and then letting the controller invoke a method on the model that references that state. The issue then is that the controller methods basically do nothing other than invoke equivalent methods on the presentation model; you end up with a layer that really is too thin and isn't pulling its weight, and the architecture looks over-engineered.

That said, if you do want to experiment with this, here's an approach that will work.

The main stumbling block here is that the `FXMLLoader` has a single `controller` instance associated with it. When it loads the FXML, it both injects elements with `fx:id` attributes into the controller, *and* associates "handler" methods in the controller with event handlers specified via `onXXX` attributes in the FXML.

The way you can make this work is to use the `FXMLLoader`'s `namespace`, which is a map from `fx:id` values to the corresponding elements. So the approach I think will work is to use the default load process to associate the handlers with your controller, and then to use a bunch of reflection to initialize `@FXML`-annotated fields in your presenter from the values in the namespace.

The latter part of that looks like:

```
private void injectFieldsIntoPresenter(FXMLLoader loader, P presenter) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException  {
    Map<String, Object> namespace = loader.getNamespace() ;
    for (Field field : presenter.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible() ;
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if (field.getAnnotation(FXML.class) != null) {
            if (namespace.containsKey(field.getName())) {
                field.set(presenter, namespace.get(field.getName()));
            }
        }
        field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
    }
}
```

Of course, your presenter also needs to perform some bindings, so we need to arrange for a method to be invoked *after* the fields have been injected. This is done for the controller class by the `FXMLLoader` by invoking any `public` or `@FXML`-annotated method called `initialize()`; so if you want the same functionality for your presenter, you can do:

```
private void initializePresenterIfPossible(P presenter) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    for (Method m : presenter.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
        boolean wasAccessible = m.isAccessible() ;
        m.setAccessible(true);
        if ("initialize".equals(m.getName()) && m.getParameterCount() == 0) { 
            if ((m.getModifiers() & Modifier.PUBLIC) != 0 || m.getAnnotation(FXML.class) != null) {
                m.invoke(presenter);
            }
        }
        m.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
    }
}
```

(You could use other schemes here, such as using the `javax.inject` annotations and simply invoking any `@PostConstruct`-annotated method.)

So a general-use loading class that wraps an `FXMLLoader` and performs these additional steps might look like the following. This has a couple of additional pieces of functionality: since both your controller and your presenter will need access to the model, it injects any `@FXML`-annotated field whose type is the same type as the model with the model instance. (Again, you can modify this as needed.)
As you can see, this functionality relies on a whole bunch of reflection: it is basically implementing a micro-framework.

```
package mvpc;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class MVPCLoader<M, V, P, C> {

    private P presenter ;
    private C controller ;
    private V view ;
    private M model ;

    public V load(URL resource, M model, P presenter) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException  {

        if (view != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("FXML can only be loaded once by a MVPCLoader instance");
        }

        this.model = model ;
        this.presenter = presenter ;

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
        loader.setControllerFactory(this::controllerFactory);
        view =  loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController() ;
        injectInto(presenter, model);
        injectFieldsIntoPresenter(loader, presenter);
        initializePresenterIfPossible(presenter);
        return view ;
    }

    public P getPresenter() {
        return presenter ;
    }

    public M getModel() {
        return model ;
    }

    public C getController() {
        return controller ;
    }

    private void initializePresenterIfPossible(P presenter) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        for (Method m : presenter.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            boolean wasAccessible = m.isAccessible() ;
            m.setAccessible(true);
            if ("initialize".equals(m.getName()) && m.getParameterCount() == 0) { 
                if ((m.getModifiers() & Modifier.PUBLIC) != 0 || m.getAnnotation(FXML.class) != null) {
                    m.invoke(presenter);
                }
            }
            m.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
        }
    }

    private void injectFieldsIntoPresenter(FXMLLoader loader, P presenter) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException  {
        Map<String, Object> namespace = loader.getNamespace() ;
        for (Field field : presenter.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible() ;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.getAnnotation(FXML.class) != null) {
                if (namespace.containsKey(field.getName())) {
                    field.set(presenter, namespace.get(field.getName()));
                }
            }
            field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
        }
    }

    private C controllerFactory(Class<?> type) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            C controller = (C) type.newInstance();
            injectInto(controller, model);
            return controller ;
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            if (exc instanceof RuntimeException) throw (RuntimeException)exc ;
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
    }

    private void injectInto(Object target, Object value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException  {
        for (Field field : target.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible() ;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(target) == null && field.getType() == value.getClass() && field.getAnnotation(FXML.class) != null) {
                field.set(target, value);
            }
            field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
        }
    }
}
```

Techniques for doing this were inspired by looking at the source code for [afterburner.fx](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx).

Here's a quick test using this class:

```
package mvpc;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class PresentationModel {

    private final IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public IntegerProperty countProperty() {
        return count ;
    }

    public final int getCount() {
        return countProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCount(int count) {
        countProperty().set(count);
    }

    public final void increment() {
        setCount(getCount() + 1);
    }
}
```

```
package mvpc;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Presenter {

    @FXML
    private PresentationModel model ;

    @FXML
    private Label display ;

    public void initialize() {
        display.textProperty().bind(model.countProperty().asString("Count: %d"));
    }
}
```

```
package mvpc;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private PresentationModel model ;

    @FXML
    private void increment() {
        model.increment();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mvpc.Controller" spacing="5" alignment="CENTER">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="10" left="10" bottom="10" right="10"/>
    </padding>
    <Label fx:id="display"/>
    <Button text="Increment" onAction="#increment"/>
</VBox>
```

```
package mvpc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MVPCTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        PresentationModel model = new PresentationModel();
        Presenter presenter = new Presenter();
        MVPCLoader<PresentationModel, Parent, Presenter, Controller> loader = new MVPCLoader<>();
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"), model, presenter));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. That's a very nice solution. I will check it deeply and I will also check afterburner.fx.

Comment: My base idea is to create a framework (because I did not find one) that allows me to quickly and easily create small (but sometimes in the background very complex) desktop tools in my work.